# Can Python objects call methods that are lower in the inheritence stack?

Tags: python, inheritance

I am trying to watch a video on python tricks shown [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7lmCu8wz8ro&list=FLP2EPm8Dj0t-2yG_otBnIhg&index=16&t=2520s). He is trying to demonstrate when using a higher level class when calling a method provided by the developer extending the class, that he can assure the method is written. He then wrote two classes in two different files

```
-- library.py

class Base():
    def foo(self):
        return self.bar()

-- user.py

from library import Base

class Derived(Base):
    def bar(self):
        return 'bar'
```

Now, I am confused why this would even work since the class `Base`, cannot call methods of anyone that inherits from it. For example, the following code will produce an error.

```
class Higher():

    def higher_method(self):
        print("higher method")

class Lower(Higher):

    def lower_method(self):
        print("lower method")

higher = Higher()        
higher.lower_method()
```

How is the method called when he executes the code?

Comment: `Derived().foo()` *will work* though

Comment: Maybe see it the other way around: `Derived` *inherits* all the methods from `Base`, and obviously if you'd write `def foo` inside `Derived`, it would work just fine.

Comment: In short that is because an instance of `Base` does not know about any of the classes that inherit from it. Therefore an instance of `Base` does not have methods from any classes that inherit from it.

Comment: To point this out though: Writing `Base` like this is *unsafe*, since indeed the class cannot guarantee that `bar` is implemented, which will lead to runtime errors if it's not. That's where *abstract* classes and abstract method definitions come into play.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `Derived().foo()`, the object bound to `self` in `Base.foo` is *not* an instance of `Base`; it's an instance of `Derived`, and so its lookup will succeed for `bar`. `Base().foo()` would fail by the same logic: the instance of `Base` bound to `self` would *not* find a definition for `bar`.

In your `Higher`/`Lower` example, the same reasoning applies: an instance of `Higher` simply does not have access to a attribute named `lower_method`. The only difference is you are failing immediately, where your instance of `Higher` is bound to the global name `higher` rather than bound to the name `self` in a method that is defined by `Higher`.

Names are scoped statically, but lookups occur dynamically.